# VisualC# Cannot Change DisplayName of Control

Tags: c#, .net

So I was make the display name (content) of a Lable from another page of the GUI. After realising a public static void function can't change the Displayname because it's not static, I messed around with Events and got a Handler set up to run when there other page publishes the event.

It looks like this

```
    public void UpdateEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Event Received");
        tab1.DisplayName = Globals.tab1Name;
    }
```

When the event goes off the message box pops up but the DisplayName does not change. 
There was no errors, nothing.

The problems is not `Globals.tab1Name` because I ran it through the MessageBox and it was fine.

So I made another button, on the same page as the Lable:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tab1.DisplayName = Globals.tab1Name;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("clicked");
    }
```

This time all the code worked, lable changed and msgbox popped up.

I made another function with the same two lines of code in it, called it with the event handler, again only the msgbox works. But when I call the same function with the button it all works.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? I don't see any `DisplayName` property for a `Label` control.

Comment: Is your event raised in the UI thread? Obviously you should get an error if not, but maybe you hide the message with a `try / catch` statement somewhere else.

Comment: This is probably a cross-threading issue, but without knowing the UI framework you are using, its difficult to tell you how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBoxes pause the execution of the current thread. Therefore, when you show the MessageBox first the second line isn't hit thus the string isn't updated

Comment: I closed the Message Box and nothing happened after

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the display name as a parameter for the form load.  By default the form has sender and e as parameters, but you can always add your own too.